# NgRoute does not work TemplateUrl

Tags: angularjs

I really don`t know why my routes does not work. Look:

I have a simple dir like:

```
build/ 
.../app/ 
....../app.js 
.../templates/ 
....../dashboard/ 
........./dashboard.html
```

When i use:

```
 angular.module("Proposal.Dashboard").config(configRouter);

     function configRouter($routeProvider) {
         $routeProvider.when("/", {
             controller: "DashboardController",
             templateUrl: "../templates/dashboard/dashboard.html",
             controllerAs: "dashboardVm"
         })
     }
```

It should works. But does not, somebody has an ideia?

Comment: It looks good based on the information you have posed. How are you running the app? Is the website pointing to the build directory? Check the network tab to see if there is any 404's.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Where & how your index.html file looks like? How your module is defined.